# Spring Data Rest projection sorting

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest, projection

I have a projection for my entity and I need to sort it by field of inner class. This is part of my entities:

```
class Person {
    UUID guid;
    Set<DisabilityHistory> disabilityHistory;
}
class DisabilityHistory {
    Date createdDate;
}
```

I know about `sort` param but request like `api/person/search?projection=myProjection&sort=disabilityHistory.createdDate,asc` doesn't work. The only solution I have found is using `@OrderBy` annotation in my entity but in this case it will sorted always and I worried about performance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will not work as you are trying to sort an inner field in your entity, so you can't do it on DB level. The way I've used it is by sorting it in the [Projection](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts.projections) class using [SpEL](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html). This is an example of how you can do it:

```
@Projection(
        name = "sorted",
        types = Person.class
)
public interface PersonProjection {

    @Value("#{@personProjectionHelper.sortedByDisabilityHistory(target.disabilityHistory)}")
    List<DisabilityHistory> getDisabilityHistory();
}
```

And implement the sorting in Java:

```
@Component
public class PersonProjectionHelper {

    public List<DisabilityHistory> sortByDisabilityHistory(final List<DisabilityHistory> list) {
        // do the sorting on Java level
    }
}
```

Comment: Do we have to somehow inject PersonProjectionHelper or is it picked up automatically? If so - how to do that?

Comment: No, you just declare it as a component and it will be picked up automatically, so if it is in the spring context - you just use it by bean name, in this case `personProjectionHelper` .

Comment: Yeah, thanks it worked. I've forgot to add hash at the beginning of @-Value declaration and was getting 500 with some unclear stack trace. I thought it's because it cannot find my @-Component.